# What is the effect of second argument in _builtin_prefetch()?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, prefetch

The GCC doc [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) specifies the usage of _buitin_prefetch.

Third argument is perfect. 
If it is 0, compiler generates prefetchtnta (%rax) instruction
If it is 1, compiler generates prefetcht2 (%rax) instruction
If it is 2, compiler generates prefetcht1 (%rax) instruction
If it is 3 (default), compiler generates prefetcht0 (%rax) instruction.

If we vary third argument the opcode already changed accordingly.

But second argument do not seem to have any effect.

```
__builtin_prefetch(&x,1,2);
__builtin_prefetch(&x,0,2);
__builtin_prefetch(&x,0,1);
__builtin_prefetch(&x,0,0);
```

The above is the sample piece of code, that generated:

The following is the assembly:

```
 27:    0f 18 10                prefetcht1 (%rax)
  2a:   48 8d 45 fc             lea    -0x4(%rbp),%rax
  2e:   0f 18 10                prefetcht1 (%rax)
  31:   48 8d 45 fc             lea    -0x4(%rbp),%rax
  35:   0f 18 18                prefetcht2 (%rax)
  38:   48 8d 45 fc             lea    -0x4(%rbp),%rax
  3c:   0f 18 00                prefetchnta (%rax)
```

One can observe the change in opcodes wrt 3rd argument. But even if I changed 2nd argument (that specifies read or write), the assembly code remains the same. <27,2a> and <2e,31>. So it not giving any information to the machine. Then what is the purpose of the second argument?

Comment: The documentation is very clear. Which instructions it generates for a specific architecture of course depends on the features available. For some architectures it will not emit any instruction at all. So did you check which prefetch instructions your specific x86 target provides? What they actually do? And how they are related to the arguments? The instruction manuals for Intel and AMD are available for free download.

Answer (score 7):

As Margaret points out, one of the args is *rw*.

Baseline x86-64 (SSE2) does not include **write-prefetch instructions**, but they exist as ISA extensions.  As usual, compilers won't use them unless you tell them you're compiling for a target that supports it.  (But they will safely run as a NOP on any non-ancient CPU.)

The two instructions are: [PREFETCHW](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PREFETCHW.html) (into L1d cache like PREFETCHT0) and [PREFETCHWT1](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PREFETCHWT1.html) (into L2 cache like [PREFETCHT1](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/prefetchh)).  **They prefetch a line into Exclusive MESI state** by sending out an RFO (Read-For-Ownership). This invalidates every other copy of the line in every other core.  From that state, the store buffer can commit data to a line (and flip it to Modified) without any further off-core traffic.  Or if not modified before eviction, can simply be dropped.

> The PREFETCHW instruction is merely a hint and does not affect program behavior. If executed, this instruction moves data closer to the processor and invalidates other cached copies in anticipation of the line being written to in the future.

They have nearly the same machine encoding, same `OF 0D` opcode, differing only in `/1` or `/2` in the ModRM `/r` field.  Just like how read-prefetch PREFETCHT0/T1/T2/NTA share an opcode and are differentiated only by `/0` (NTA), `/1` (T0), etc. in the ModRM `/r` field.  Using `/r` bits as extra opcode bits is not unique; other one-operand and immediate instructions also do that.

related: [Difference between prefetch for read or write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003361/difference-between-prefetch-for-read-or-write/30259403#30259403)

---

PREFETCHW originally appeared in [AMD's 3DNow!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DNow!), but has its own feature bit so that CPUs can indicate support for it but not other 3DNow! (packed-`float` in MMX regs) instructions.

PREFETCHWT1 also has its own CPUID feature bit, but might be associated with AVX512PF.  It appears to only be available in Xeon Phi (Knight's Landing / Knight's Mill), not mainstream Skylake-AVX512, same as AVX512PF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512).  (Evidence: According to [Intel's Future Extensions manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/c5/15/architecture-instruction-set-extensions-programming-reference.pdf), CPUID with EAX=7/ECX=0 gives a feature bitmap in ECX including *Bit 00: PREFETCHWT1 (Intel® Xeon Phi™ only.)*  Also [mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2014-02/msg01330.html).

---

**`__builtin_prefetch(p,1,2);` compiles as follows with GCC**:

- PREFETCHT1 with no `-m` options, or `-march=haswell` or older Intel.
- PREFETCHW with an AMD target, like `-march=k8` or `-march=bdver2` (Piledriver).
- PREFETCHW with `-march=broadwell` or newer Intel SnB-family, and/or `-mprfchw` for any arch.
- PREFETCHWT1 with [`-mprefetchwt1`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html).  (If PREFETCHW is also available, gcc uses it for locality=3, but PREFETCHWT1 for locality<=2.)  GCC for some reason doesn't enable this as part of `-march=knl` or `-march=knm`, but clang does.  I think this is an oversight in GCC.
- `-mprefetchwt1` implies `-mprfchw`.  See also the [x86 options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) section in the GCC manual for more about `-march=native` vs. `-march=whatever` to enable a set of ISA extensions and set `-mtune=whatever` appropriately.

Check it out on the [Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5AHoZAagC0AWwAOxAGbIEAd3nyQ8zCyYAjBpnkAFAErYAYtgAqAYQASAdQ4AGAIJylNWJMDUwCbR0CWh9fGICVJnEEDgBmABEAaxYGeRJ5LOUDeWRmNnyWVB1BeQIEPGq8FhKRLGrbB2d3Dyd6eVMRAnlgZGR5dFRMQRYwKQI4hQSk1LTTYlQmdB1MBhy8lkwt4iLjMws2u0dXT3nAxO1l1gBPeSZldGOTc0nrC87rvxiADdUHh3uoQhBgaD5AAqVQASnkHAA7Hw/PoAPoY/p4BgERoY8GhcIICCqUj0Ljw1I8fQBBioZBMBiER6pFzLLjyImYYjnDpXbq0eQ6BDGF6Api406YGKY7EiXH4liE4LE7RkimkFLUlK0%2BT0xnM1lI9Ipblq3n8y5dIyA8Wi8XtG2eHryeoSqXML4xOXyLE4vEEnkkzXebW6tG%2BeWB5WqkJhDXk8NUml%2BgOKoMqkNJ0jh2iR9MKpXBy2h5N5wsA5FpGJSeGMaQAVikpBY0m8rdQ0g5vH48mEYgkSK4KVorYIHfrDYyIBSABYAHTz%2BcANi4AE5vMjkbQN1x5/vG1J56321JO6Ru1JW4IQOHJxf66Q4LAkGg1LjeeRKB/VF/iBAYAAA4UlIDQlStShTCnUhTEaRJHmkcdSA/ZRjAIAB5bIkKfUgsGUVhgAsWD8GCZB8XtO88MwAAPTBkAGSQpBQxoCG2WCWVWRCXAwZiUIIYg8GUZDn1Kdh%2BH4Rg8FMO9IAbVBVHxVAWGoxZ7nSBAmEELYdiUWjRkUTDzSUQQCHQZZgBYERaGFRQPGZHJ7LowSmCUDQKkUe1iFMVBBEwRRtOUW9RHESQC2PFs21g69aOA1dFFXechhGeRgMXc0IFwQg8m4MdSHkXjPwsI48oLQrJN4Ccp3hGc5y4RcuC4bwUmRJtgI3edkXnWhkVXY9T2ivDr1ve9SEfTsG1fKAYEQFBUGK78KAgP8AKA0DwMgvloNg%2BCTGIXCULQjDsIYXDLwIoiSLwsiGMoyZYLohimNE8gWHYhhOJk4geL417BOE0SG3ElBKoELi5IgBSlLwFS1KCBMSUiOzCKWdIClM8zLOs2ylAcvTnNo1z3M87zfP8wLBEKRQDKUYz5BCodwuB5szxi6Q4oSpKUtGdLMuyohStHXoiv/EqRxSKkKr7KrxpquqUhSDLFZV1XVYG1sRKbcNz0vEahDGibn2miB3wWsWlt/c21pKIjkW8cMILxKCIBgvC9sQ17jve07ztbS62Gui68HI%2B7qMvJ7GPY162I4vCuJ%2Bg7eKwf6hJElixKI0GZfBmTIeh5TVOkdTknRlhqfxpyPBcn79MM4zGbCugWakKLda7Dn4sS5LbbKZFF28Af5Cy/BBYlkXrfFvKdWlvhZaN2rSDFDZeUoFvBq1nX2ZvA2H3l0hZ0V5W1ZPsDPqkFI2eG6RqqfRfz64K%2B9ZvuW74bbzBFh9t5yAA%3D), for `-march=haswell` vs. `-march=broadwell -mprefetchwt1`.  Or modify the compiler args yourself.

`clang -O3 -march=knl`, and `gcc -O3 -march=broadwell -mprefetchwt1` make the same asm:

```
pref:
        prefetchwt1     [rdi]    #   __builtin_prefetch(p,1,2);  // KNL only, otherwise we get prefetchw
        prefetchw       [rdi]    #   __builtin_prefetch(p,1,3);

        prefetcht0      [rdi]    #   __builtin_prefetch(p,0,3);
        prefetcht1      [rdi]    #   __builtin_prefetch(p,0,2);
        prefetcht2      [rdi]    #   __builtin_prefetch(p,0,1);
        prefetchnta     [rdi]    #   __builtin_prefetch(p,0,0);
        ret
```

Also note that their [`0F 0D r/m8` machine code decodes as a multi-byte NOP](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html#x0F0D) on non-ancient CPUs that don't have the PREFETCHW or 3DNow! feature-bit.  On early 64-bit Intel CPUs, it's an illegal instruction.  (Newer versions of Windows require that PREFETCHW executes without faulting, and in that context people talk about a CPU "supporting PREFETCHW" even if it runs as a NOP).

It's possible that CPUs which support PREFETCHW but not PREFETCHWT1 will actually run PREFETCHWT1 as if it were PREFETCHW, but I haven't tested.  (It should be testable by running threads on different cores, one doing repeated stores to a location and the other doing PREFETCHWT1 vs. PREFETCHW vs. read prefetch vs. NOP, and see how the writing thread's throughput is affected.)

---

It might be preferable to use a read-intent prefetch instead of a NOP, though (like GCC does).  But you probably don't want to do a PREFETCHW and a PREFETCHT0, because too many prefetch instructions aren't a good thing.  (especially for Intel IvyBridge, which has some kind of performance bug for prefetch-instruction throughput.  But IvB would run PREFETCHW as a NOP, so you're only getting one prefetch on that uarch.)

Tuning software-prefetch is hard: too much prefetching means fewer execution resources spent doing real work, if HW prefetch does its job successfully.  See [Cost of a sub-optimal cacheline prefetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54821849/cost-of-a-sub-optimal-cacheline-prefetch) and [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126311/what-every-programmer-should-know-about-memory/47714514#47714514)

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Where to give that -march=-xxxxx.?what does this march option specifies exactly, target machine/architecture?

Comment: @ANTHONY: On the gcc command line, at compile time, obviously.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html.  I don't think it matters at link time, just while going from `.c` to `.o` (or directly to an executable).  It tells gcc what instructions it's allowed to use, and also sets `-mtune=`.

Comment: To be more precise, older versions of Windows emulated for the 3DNow! prefetch instructions for older Intel CPUs.

Comment: `PREFETCHWT1` is part of the [AVX512PF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512) set. The wikipedia article doesn't mention explicitly though. It is shown more clearly [here](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/x86/avx-512). However, although the WikiChip article says that AVX512PF is supported on both KNL and KNM, [Intel®
Architecture
Instruction Set Extensions and Future Features
Programming Reference](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/c5/15/architecture-instruction-set-extensions-programming-reference.pdf) says that it 's only supported on KNL.

Comment: That Wikipedia article does say that AVX512PF is supported on KNM and it cites that same Intel document, but that document doesn't say that.

Comment: On the other hand, the clang [source code](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Basic/Targets/X86.cpp#L272) suggests that it is supported on KNM.

Comment: @HadiBrais: I think it's safe to assume that when the `PREFETCHWT1`  was added to the future-extensions guide, Knight's Mill didn't exist yet, and/or they forgot to say "and later".  And when they later added some KNM new instructions, they missed updating KNL-only entry.  I'm sure they wouldn't have actually removed it.  But anyway, PREFETCHWT1 has a separate feature bit from AVX512PF.

Answer (score 4):

From the same link you posted:

> There are two optional arguments, *rw* and *locality*. The value of *rw* is a compile-time constant one or zero; **one means that the prefetch is preparing for a write to the memory address and zero, the default, means that the prefetch is preparing for a read.**

The x86 architecture has no distinction between a read and a write prefetch.
This doesn't mean that you should ignore the second argument as writing code in C is done to improve portability.
Even if in your machine the second argument is not used, it can be used when compiling to different architectures.

**EDIT**
As @PeterCordes pointed out in his comment, x86 actually have a prefetch instruction in anticipation of a write.
It differs from the other prefetch instructions as it invalidates other cached instanced of the line fetched (and set it to exclusive state).

Comment: PREFETCHW exists on AMD CPUs, and Intel since Broadwell.  Excellent point that even if your current compile target doesn't support it, you should still express your intent correctly so you get good asm on other targets.

Comment: Thank you @Peter , I totally missed that.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.
What is the use of specifying Read/Write in 2nd argument, wrt hardware.? How does hardware treat the things different.? It has same MSHR entries. I just want to know how hardware shows difference in treating these both R and W.!!

Comment: @ANTHONY Google for "MESI protocol", it is the protocol that x86 use to keep the cache coherent. A cache line can be in any of the four states M,E,S,I at any moment. Writing in particular states is expensive because requires extra work, the W prefetch does this extra-work in addition to fetching the data.

Comment: Can you elaborate why do hardware need to change the state in cache (M,E,S,I) as soon as it prefetches the data with 'w'. In my guess, once the prefetch is done with 'W', it is there is the cache. But it need not change the state to 'M' to reflect 'w'. Because the state change to M involves invalidations (thats what you mentioned as expensive). If the prefetch is done early or late , then the state changes will cost more as they polluted the cache.

So can we still think prefetch with 'W' will change the state.??