# How did the legacy 3DNow! instruction set store results to memory or integer registers?

Tags: x86, legacy, instruction-set, amd-processor, mmx

Just for fun I'm reviewing legacy (deprecated) instructions from [3DNow! set](https://support.amd.com/TechDocs/21928.pdf) introduced by AMD, and I'm trying to understand how were they used. All instructions seem to be encoded following this pattern:

```
instruction destination_MMn_register_operand, source_MMn_register_or_memory_operand
```

where `destinationRegister` = `destinationRegister` -operation- `source`

Like, for instance, `pfadd mm0, mmword ptr [rcx]` (`0F 0F 01 9E`):

[image]

Would add 2 packed floats from memory pointed by `rcx` to 2 packed floats stored in `mm0` and keep result in `mm0`.

So it seems like those 3DNow instructions always have an `mm` register as a destination.

But how were you supposed to get the results out of those `mm` registers?

In other words, there's no `mov mmword ptr [rcx], mm0`, or `mov rax, mm0` instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @harold says, storing to memory or extracting to an integer register is already covered by MMX `movq` (both) or `movd` (low), or `punpckhdq`+`movd` to extract just the high `float`.  (Or with [MMXEXT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_MMX) introduced with SSE1, `pshufw` to copy-and-shuffle into another register, not destroying the original.)  Similarly for loading.

```
 PF2ID  mm0, [esi]     ; 3DNow! load 2 floats and convert to 32-bit integer
; basic MMX instructions to use the result
; could do the same thing with 32-bit FP bit patterns
 movq  [edi], mm0      ; store both
 movd  eax, mm0        ; extract low half
 punpckhdq  mm0, mm0   ; broadcast high half
 movd  edx, mm0        ; extract high half
```

I used 32-bit addressing modes so this code can work in 32-bit mode for compat with CPUs before K8.  In 64-bit mode you have SSE2 which makes 3DNow! mostly pointless.  Except for working with exactly 2 floats at a time on CPUs like K8 where 128-bit SIMD instructions like `addps` run as 2 uops.  Or if you had some existing code developed for 3DNow! and haven't ported it to SSE2 yet.  64-bit mode does have `movq rax, mm0`, just like `movq rax, xmm0`.

---

The one thing you can't do is turn an 3DNow! float into an x87 80-bit float without a store/reload.

What might have been potentially useful is a version of EMMS that expands a 32-bit `float` into an 80-bit x87 `long double` in `st0`, along with setting the FPU back into x87 mode instead of MMX mode<sup>1</sup>.  Or maybe even do that for multiple `mm` registers into multiple x87 registers?

i.e. it would be a shortcut for `movd dword [esp], mm0` / `emms` / `fld dword [esp]` to set up for further scalar FP after a SIMD reduction.

Remember that these are IEEE754 `float`s; you normally don't want them in integer registers unless you're picking apart their bit-fields (e.g. for an `exp` or `log` implementation), but you can do that with MMX shift/mask instructions.

`PF2ID` or `PF2IW` to convert to 32-bit or 16-bit integer of course give you integer data in MMX registers, at which point you're in normal MMX territory.

---

But `movd` and `fld` are cheap, so they didn't bother making a special instruction just to save the reload latency.  Also, it might have been slow to implement as a single instruction.  Even though x86 is not a RISC ISA, having one really complex instruction is often slower than multiple simpler instructions, especially before decoding to multiple uops was fully a thing. Look at in-order P5 Pentium for an example of how using a RISCy subset of x86 was more efficient there, allowing it to pipeline and pair better if you avoid instructions like `push`/`pop`.  (That's all changed; push/pop and memory-destination ALU instructions are fine if you need the load/store anyway, and don't have a use for the value in a register.)

3dNow!'s [`femms` leaves the MMX/3dNow! register contents undefined](http://softpixel.com/%7Ecwright/programming/simd/3dn.php), only setting the tag words to unused instead of preserving the mapping from MMX registers to/from x87 register contents.  See http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/AMD-3Dnow.pdf for an official AMD manual.  IDK if AMD's microarchitectures just dropped the register-renaming info or what, but probably making store / femms / x87-load the fast way saves a lot of transistors.

Or even FEMMS is still somewhat slow, so they don't want to encourage coders to leave/re-enter MMX/3dNow! mode at all often.

---

**Fun fact: 3dNow! `PREFETCHW` (prefetch with write intent) is still used, and has its own CPUID feature bit.**

See my answer on [What is the effect of second argument in _builtin_prefetch()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513280/what-is-the-effect-of-second-argument-in-builtin-prefetch/40516861#40516861)

Intel CPUs soon added support for decoding it as a NOP (so software like 64-bit Windows can use it without checking), but Broadwell and later actually prefetch with a RFO to get the cache line in MESI Exclusive state, rather than Shared, so it can flip to Modified without additional off-core traffic.

The CPUID feature bit indicates that it really will prefetch.

---

**Footnote 1**:

Remember that the MMX registers alias the x87 registers, so no new OS support was needed to save/restore architectural state on context switches.  It wasn't until [SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info) that we got new architectural state.  So it wasn't until SSE2+3dNow! that a 3dNow! `float` to SSE2 `double` could make sense without switching back to x87 mode.  And you could [`movq2dq xmm0, mm0`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVQ2DQ.html) + [`cvtps2pd xmm0, xmm0`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTPS2PD.html).

They could have had a float->double in a `mm` register, but the `fld` / `fst` hardware was only designed for `float` or `double`->80-bit and 80-bit->`float` or `double`.  And the use-case for that is limited; if you're using 3dNow!, just stick to `float`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Very interesting. Btw, I noted after perusing AMD documentation (linked in my answer) that they refer to single-precision floating point numbers that they use for 3Dnow instructions as having a 24-bit significand. But from what I understand the Intel's traditional 32-bit floats use a 23-bit mantissa. Are 3Dnow's packed floats using a different floating-point format than Intel?

Comment: @MikeF: I don't think so.  Almost certainly just a terminology issue; AMD is counting the implicit bit in the significand.  Wikipedia has a nice article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32) which describes IEEE binary32 as 24 bit precision, 23 stored. (For subnormal numbers, the first bit of the significand is 0, instead of the usual 1. So an all-zero or not exponent implies the leading bit.)  BTW, "significand" is the preferred terminology, but mantissa is more widely used.  It's the same thing.

Comment: Oh, OK. I was just curious. Who knows, AMD could've invented their own floating point format. It doesn't matter at this point though, as 3DNow is almost 99% dead anyway. I think the only thing that still remains from it is the `prefetchw` instruction. [Windows uses it](https://i.imgur.com/kAXzPqO.png) for pretty much every kernel-mode call to preload some kernel structure there. As for `FEMMS` instruction that you pointed out, I think it's AMD only. It was #UD'ing on all of my Intel systems.

Comment: @MikeF: Yes, `femms` is part of 3dNow!, and wasn't adopted as an MMX/SSE extension.  I mentioned it because CPU vendors design their instruction-set extensions to be convenient for their own current microarchitectures.  (Another example of that: Intel's SSE `cvtsi2ss xmm0, eax` leaves the upper bytes of XMM0 unmodified, probably so it can be single uop on Pentium III, which splits 128-bit vector ops into 2.  But that short-sighted false dependency has led to gcc choosing to `pxor xmm0,xmm0` first, to avoid the risk of creating a loop-carried dep chain or coupling to a slow dep chain.

Comment: Oh, Peter, also meant to bring up. Does Intel support `prefetch` instruction (the one without fetching for "write")? It seems like it's AMD-only, a legacy from the 3Dnow set, but Intel documentation is surprisingly silent about it.

Comment: @MikeF: regular `prefetch` have been supported on Intel for a long time.  http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PREFETCHh.html doesn't even list an ISA extension, so it may even predate MMX?  The NASM manual's appendix lists when insns were new, even back to 186.  https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdocb.html says `PREFETCH` was new in Pentium, while `PREFETCHT0/1/2` / `PREFETCHNTA` were new in Katmai (first-gen PIII, so I guess with SSE).  IDK what they mean about plain `prefetch`; maybe there was an earlier version of the opcode that ignored the `/r` field in ModRM and just prefetched.

Comment: Hah, very interesting. Thanks for sharing. I was also curious about that strange behavior of the `cvtsi2ss` instruction. Although IMO, it's one of those SISC instructions that you'd be hard pressed to find in your average code. As for the prefetch, then no, I was referring to an even more ancient instruction. The one with the `0F 0D modR/M` encoding, the one that doesn't even specify which cache level to use: L1, L2.

Comment: @MikeF: Compilers use `cvtsi2sd` all the time in code that uses FP and integer values together (`double` is more common than `float`).  e.g. https://godbolt.org/g/M52CXv.  SSE2 kept the unnecessary-dependency behaviour for that instruction too, so gcc emits two dep-breaking `pxor` instructions.  (Clang is more optimistic).  Fun trick: with AVX you can use the same zeroed register as a no-dependency source, like `vcvtsi2sd xmm0, xmm7, eax`, not destroying the zeroed register.  Clang uses this sometimes.  Lots of code doesn't get auto-vectorized but is still perf-relevant.

Comment: @MikeF: Looks like my first guess was insufficient for `0F 0D` prefetch, because clearly it's not the same encoding as the SSE prefetches.  IDK why the NASM manual flags that as `PENT,3DNOW`.  (Note that `0F 0D /1` is prefetchw, so the /r field must matter for the non-write prefetch on CPUs that actually implement it.

Comment: pshufw won't work with just MMX as it was an instruction added with SSE1. Your first sentence seems to suggest pshufw works with MMX.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: It seems I wrote this before I knew that some instructions on MMX registers were new with SSE1, with Katmai P3, not Pentium MMX.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much from the date of the answer. No problem.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Ok, finished updating, that wasn't the only thing worth revising in the answer.  And BTW, Intel's manuals aren't very explicit about CPU features required, e.g. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pshufw doesn't mention anything about SSE1, unfortunately. But ECM's instruction-set reference derives from NASM's appendix is accurate: (https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Actually there are, namely `movd` and `movq`. These instructions are not part of 3DNow!, they were already present in MMX which 3DNow! is an extension to. That is also why 3DNow! includes a very incomplete-seeming set of integer operations.