# Storing a general purpose register in st0

Tags: x86, floating-point, x86-64, x87

If I have some value (bit pattern, let's say all zeros) in `rax`, can I store it in `st0` without storing and loading from memory?

Comment: No. [required filler]

Answer (score 3):

I think you actually want this for [Long latency instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58566439/long-latency-instruction)
 where `movd`/`movq` + `sqrtss` or `sqrtsd` works more easily than ?? -> fsqrt.

**Coupling an integer dependency into an x87 dependency can be done with [`fcmovcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fcmovcc) through integer flags** instead of by transferring a bit-pattern.  On Skylake that's a 4-uop instruction, but it's 4 ALU uops.

In the other direction,  **`fcomi`+`setcc`** or `cmovcc` or even just `fcom`+`fnstsw ax`.

As @Hadi points out, you can create values in x87 registers with `fldz` (1 uop) or `fld1` (2 uops).  Then make that dependent on whatever you want using `fcmovne st0, st1` or similar.

---

**Possible answer, not really fully researched since it's unlikely to be useful** to you (probably involving microcoded `emms`: 10 uops on Skylake, 31 uops on Haswell.)

**Maybe you can use `movq mm0, rax` and then `emms` to leave MMX state**.  This marks all the x87 register tags as "empty".

On current AMD, FEMMS is identical to EMMS, according to [AMD's 2018-may PDF ISA reference manual](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/26569_APM_V5.pdf#page=48), but I seem to recall reading that FEMMS on older AMD CPUs left the x87 registers undefined.  Maybe that's usable for something.  It does still set tag words, so the undefined contents is probably only relevant for cases that were maybe expecting to find `mm0..7` contents still there after EMMS and then running another MMX instruction.  Or to find the data in `fxsave` state.

**The 64-bit MMX registers alias the significands (mantissas) of the 80-bit x87 registers.** (I think).  The `st0..7` stack maps onto those underlying 80-bit registers starting at the one indexed by the 3-bit TOP field in the x87 status word.  (http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap1.htm describes this nicely with the analogy of a revolver barrel).

I'm not sure if this is really usable, but I don't think `emms` clears `mm` / st register contents, only x87 tags.  ([Intel's vol.2 entry for `emms`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/emms) says "Sets the values of all the tags in the x87 FPU tag word to empty (all 1s)"

> If a floating-point instruction loads one of the registers in the x87 FPU data register stack before the x87 FPU tag word has been reset by the EMMS instruction, an x87 floating-point register stack overflow can occur that will result in an x87 floating-point exception or incorrect result.

It only says "can", not "will".  Perhaps with the x87 metadata in a known state, you can mix MMX instructions and x87 instructions with some kind of consistent behaviour?  At least on a specific microarchitecture.

You can't read an x87 register whose tag word is `11` (meaning empty), and there's no `funfree`, just [`ffree`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ffree) to set a single tag word to `11` (without affecting the Top-of-stack pointer or the contents).

You'd have to `fstenv` and modify the tag word in the saved x87 state metadata (28 bytes including padding in 32/64-bit mode), then [`fldenv`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fldenv).

Or you could have a predefined x87 "environment" ready for `fldenv` with some tag words set to not-in-use.  (But Agner Fog doesn't even time that instruction.  It's obviously going to be microcoded, and probably slow.)  You might be able to use that without `emms`, but it's still one microcoded instruction.

related: [Query about legacy 3DNow! instruction set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715392/query-about-legacy-3dnow-instruction-set) has some links I dug up a while ago about `femms` and how little 3dNow! can interact with SSE.  Hmm, apparently it does still set the tag word to all unused, but doesn't preserve a known mapping between `mm0..7` and x87 registers.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of instructions that you can use to load a constant onto the FPU register stack. I think the most useful ones here are `FLD1` and `FLDZ`, which load +1.0 and +0.0 onto the stack, respectively. If the only possible integers that `RAX` may hold are 1 and 0, then you can conditionally execute `FLD1` or `FLDZ`.

In general, any 64-bit integer in the unsigned or two's complement formats can be represented in the 80-bit extended-precision floating-point format. It's possible to load any integer value found in `RAX` onto the FPU stack with zero memory accesses. This can be achieved by using a series of x87 arithmetic instructions, possibly executed in a loop whose trip count is maintained in a GP register. One way would be to use `FADD` (or `FSUB` for negative integers) until `st0` contains the desired integer value, although this can be very slow for large (absolute) values. One possible optimization that works for integers that are powers of 2 is to load the constant +1.0, add one using `FADD` to get the number 2, and then use `FMUL` until the desired power of 2 is reached. Another method that may be faster in some cases is to first factorize the integer in `RAX`, construct each of the prime factors using `FADD`, and then multiply the prime factors using `FMUL`.

All of these instructions are supported on all Intel and AMD x86 processors.