# Long latency instruction

Tags: optimization, x86, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization, microbenchmark

I would like a long-latency single-uop x86<sup>1</sup> instruction, in order to create long dependency chains as part of testing microarchitectural features.

Currently I'm using `fsqrt`, but I'm wondering is there is something better.

Ideally, the instruction will score well on the following criteria:

- Long latency
- Stable/fixed latency
- One or a few uops (especially: not microcoded)
- Consumes as few uarch resources as possible (load/store buffers, page walkers, etc)
- Able to chain (latency-wise) with itself
- Able to chain input and out with GP registers
- Doesn't interfere with normal OoO execution (beyond whatever ROB, RS, etc, resources it consumes)

So `fsqrt` is OK in most senses, but the latency isn't that long and it seems hard to chain with GP regs.

---

<sup>1</sup> On modern Intel x86 in particular, with bonus points if it also works well on AMD Zen*.

Answer (score 4):

Mainstream Intel CPUs don't have any very long latency single-uop integer instructions.  There are integer ALUs for 1-cycle latency uops on all ALU ports, and a 3-cycle-latency pipelined ALU on port 1.  I think AMD is similar.

The div/sqrt unit is the only truly high-latency ALU, but integer div/idiv are microcoded on Intel so yes, use FP where div/sqrt are typically single-uop instructions.

AMD's integer `div` / `idiv` are 2-uop instructions (presumably to write the 2 outputs), with data-dependent latency.

Also, AMD Bulldozer/Piledriver (where 2 integer cores share a SIMD/FP unit) has pretty high latency for `movd xmm, r32` (10c 2 uops) and `movd r32, xmm` (8c 1 uop).  Steamroller shortens that by 1c each.  Ryzen has 3-cycle 1 uop in either direction.

`movd` to/from XMM regs is cheap on Intel: single-uop with 1-cycle (Broadwell and earlier) or 2-cycle latency (Skylake).  (https://agner.org/optimize/)

---

**`sqrtss` has fixed latency (on IvB and later), other than maybe with subnormal inputs**.  If your chain-with-integer involves just `movd xmm, r32` of an arbitrary integer bit-pattern, you might want to set DAZ/FTZ to remove the possibility of FP assists.  NaN inputs are fine; that doesn't cause a slowdown for SSE/AVX math, only x87.

Other CPUs (Sandybridge and earlier, and all AMD) have variable-latency `sqrtss` so you probably want to control the starting bit-pattern there.

Same goes if you want to **use `sqrtsd` for higher latency per uop than `sqrtss`**.  It's still variable latency even on Skylake.  (15-16 cycles).

**You can assume that the latency is a pure function of the input bit-pattern**, so starting a chain of `sqrtss` instructions with the same input every time will give the same sequence of latencies.  Or with a starting input of `0.0`, `1.0`, `+inf`, or `NaN`, you'll get *the same* latency for every uop in the sequence.

(Simple inputs like 1.0 and 0.0 (few significant figures in the input and output) presumably run with the lowest latency.  sqrt(1.0) = 1.0 and sqrt(0) = 0, so these are self-perpetuating.  Same for sqrt(NaN) = NaN)

**You might use `and reg, 0` or other non-dep-breaking zeroing as part of your chain to control the input bit-pattern**.  Or perhaps `or reg, -1` to create NaN.  Then you can get fixed latency on Sandybridge or earlier, and on AMD including Zen.

Or perhaps `pinsrw xmm0, eax, 7` (2 uops for port 5 on Intel) to only modify the high qword of an XMM, leaving the bottom as known `0.0` or `1.0`.  Probably cheaper to just `and` with 0 and use `movd`, unless port-5 pressure is a non-issue.

---

**To create a throughput bottleneck (not latency)**, your best bet on Skylake is `vsqrtpd ymm` - 1 uop for p0,  latency = 15-16, throughput = 9-12.

On Broadwell and earlier, it was 3 uops (2p0 p15), but Skylake I think widened the SIMD divider (in preparation for AVX512 I guess).

Answer (score 2):

`vsqrtss` might be somewhat better than `fsqrt` since it at least satisfies relatively easy chaining with GP registers (since GP <-> vector is just a `movd` away).

Comment: I assume you searched Agner Fog's instruction tables to identify suitable candidates? I looked at the tables for SkylakeX and couldn't find anything better than `vsqrtss` given the lengthy list of requirements.

Comment: @njuffa I scanned through, but I don't want to say I was exhaustive. Certainly there might be one I didn't consider, or perhaps a totally different approach is available not reflected in Agner's table (e.g., some way to trigger long latency with an instruction that isn't normally long latency).

Comment: @njuffa - note also that I don't think all the criteria can be satisfied at once, so there remains to point out "if you want really long latency but are willing to give up XYZ then try `foo`" type of stuff.