# Can't use _m_prefetchw intrinsic with gcc/clang -march=native on older Intel CPU?

Tags: c, x86, clang, intrinsics, prefetch

I ran into this problem while compiling my project with **Clang**. I want to use the intrinsic function **_m_prefetchw** for that I included x86intrin.h, but for some reason my flow is not reaching the _m_prefetchw  definition.
I checked the x86intrin.h header file of **Clang** and I dont have the **__PRFCHW__** defined in order to include prfchwintrin.h although I do have **PREFETCHW** supported by my PC (I ran coreinfo to know this).

does anyone know why **__PRFCHW__**  isn't defined although I have **PREFETCHW** supported?

code example:

```
#include <x86intrin.h>

int main(){
    int i = 10;
    _m_prefetchw(&i);
    return 0;
}
```

After running I get the error `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _m_prefetchw referenced in function main`

I dug into my clang include header files and found this in x86intrin.h:

```
#if !defined(_MSC_VER) || __has_feature(modules) || defined(__PRFCHW__)
#include <prfchwintrin.h>
#endif
```

And `_m_prefetchw` is defined in the prfchwintrin.h file.

My processor is Intel Xeon E5-2690, Clang version is 9.0.1.

Comment: Please reduce your code to [mre] (including compiler version and compile options) and post that here.

Comment: The comment by @chtz is very relevant, as are your clang version. Now, have you checked (with `objdump`) if your binary contains the prefetch instruction? Do you pass `-march` flags to `clang`? Can you compile an inline assembly snippet with this instruction? Finally, will the `__builtin_prefetch` work for your needs?

Comment: Thanks I updated the question, please tell me if you have any more comments.

Comment: I didn't pass the -march flag, because I want to compile on my machines arch.
I want to know why _m_prefetchw is not defined.

Comment: If you want to compile for your machine's own architecture, use `-march=native`.  By default clang will compile for whatever architecture was selected when it was built, which is usually some "lowest common denominator" model that isn't assumed to support this instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm still getting the same error even with the flag set. With -march=broadwell it does compile but I want to know why its not compiling on my machines processor.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  Right, older Intel CPUs can run it as a NOP, but only Broadwell and later actually advertizes the CPU feature in its CPUID, and only Broadwell and later actually do anything besides a NOP.  (AMD CPUs support it properly).  So I assume your CPU is a Haswell or older.  [What is the effect of second argument in \_builtin\_prefetch()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40513280).  So `-march=native` only includes `-mprfchw` if it will actually have an effect.  Related: [Windows 10 64-bit requirements: Does my CPU support PrefetchW?](https://superuser.com/posts/comments/1645066)

Comment: What actual CPU model do you have?

Comment: I did mention it in the question "although I do have PREFETCHW supported by my PC (I ran coreinfo to know this)." and by the coreinfo details my CPU does support PREFETCHW. I have Intel Xeon E5-2690 processor.

Comment: Right, just noticed that at the bottom. Earlier I only saw the coreinfo details which is apparently only checking for "won't fault", not for the CPUID feature bit and/or actually having a performance effect.  i.e. I could tell the coreinfo result must be useless for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Manually use `-mprfchw` to tell the compiler to let you use `_m_prefetchw` even when compiling for a `-march=` where `prefetchw` is only a NOP.**

`-march=native` only includes `-mprfchw` if it will actually have an effect.  See [What is the effect of second argument in _builtin_prefetch()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40513280) for more details on how compilers "think about" availability of prefetch instructions and CPUID.

---

Your E5-2690 is a Sandybridge, older than Broadwell which introduced (on the Intel side) real support for PREFETCHW.

Any non-ancient Intel CPUs can run `prefetchw` as a NOP (http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html#gen_note_NOP_0F0D), but only Broadwell and later actually advertizes the CPU feature in its CPUID, and only Broadwell and later actually do anything different from a NOP.  (AMD CPUs support it as an actual prefetch into Exclusive state ever since 3DNow! introduced it.)

Running as a NOP instead of faulting is apparently necessary for installing 64-bit Windows, so a lot of discussion about "supporting" PREFETCHW revolves around not faulting, rather than its CPUID bit and actually doing anything.  For example, comments on [Windows 10 64-bit requirements: Does my CPU support PrefetchW?](https://superuser.com/posts/comments/1645066) discuss this difference in "support" (as in won't fault) vs. "support" as in actually does something.

This [forum thread](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/prefetchw-and-processors.1564876/#r12039815) mentions that P4 Nocona faults on `prefetchw`, and thus can't install Windows 8.1.  But Core2 and later do have "won't fault" support.